# How to detect if sessionStorage is going to die?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Obviously, we are able to store user data in `sessionStorage`.
Also, we can watch changes to `sessionStorage`:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
```

But what if we are also, for example, sending some info to our db and we need to do some important actions when user is done with our website, and he is closing all opened browser tabs of our website, and `sessionStorage` is about to die?

There is the event `onbeforeunload`, but it doesn't fit our issue, because many tabs of the same website can be open at once, and we cant be sure it is the last one.

So question is - can we detect when `sessionStorage` is about to die?

Comment: Each tab would have a different session storage so `onbeforeunload` works.

Comment: Store a counter of open windows of a given session. Increment on a new window, decrement on a closing window?

Comment: no, counter wont work if sessionservice for each tab works separately.

Comment: @MinusFour no, it is wont work, because we need to do something when ALL tabs of our website is closed not current one.

Comment: @terrymorse also, what about user refresh page? the counter will be updated no matter if this is new page or old page refreshed.

Comment: The task seems to be to detect when the *last* browser window viewing a specific domain is closed. That's a different problem than detecting every session close, yes?

Comment: @terrymorse in general - yes.

Comment: @WebArtisan so what if the user closes all tabs and then reopens one?

Comment: @terrymorse it will be counted as a new session

Comment: @terrymorse so I need to get the moment,  right before user closing last tab.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to detect when the last tab accessing a specific site is closing.

Assuming each tab is associated with a unique session ID, the following method should work:

Upon page load:

1. obtain session ID
2. retrieve array of active session IDs from localStorage
3. if session ID is not present in array, add it
4. store array to localStorage

Upon page unload:

1. retrieve array of active session IDs from localStorage
2. find and remove current session ID from array
3. update array to localStorage
4. if array is empty, perform your "last tab closing" action

**What About Browser Crashes?**

This scheme doesn't handle when a browser crashes. In that case, the page unload will never be detected, and localStorage will never have its array of active session IDs cleared.

One way to accommodate a crash is to set a timestamp with each session ID stored, then remove old session IDs.

```js
let sessionArr = [
  { sessionId, timestamp },
  ...
]
```

Comment: It wont work, because if user will refresh some page, It will be accepted by browser as new page and it will create a new page id, so we cant rely on page id.

Comment: @WebArtisan It should work, because a page refresh retains the session ID. Have you tried it?